# Git error: "Failed to add file public/bootstrap-multiselect/ to index."

Tags: git, github, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to make the first commit of my project, but I keep getting this message:

```
"Failed to add file public/bootstrap-multiselect/ to index."
```

By un-checking that folder from the list, I can commit all other files.

I am using the GitHub OS X client (latest version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by a .git inside bootstrap-multiselect/, which for some reason was left there by the creator. By browsing to that location and removing the .git, I can now commit the folder, along with all the other files.